# Jump to a certain item via `ListView.setSelection` when using `CursorAdapter`

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I would like to implement a **restore list view state** function on android. The idea is I save the `getFirstVisiblePosition()` when the onPause function called, and use `setSelection()` to restore the state when the onResume function called (scroll down a litter bit to match the `getFirstVisiblePosition()`). The code looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    selectedItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    getSharedPreferences(TAG, MODE_PRIVATE)
            .edit()
            .putInt("list_selection", selectedItemPosition)
            .commit();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final int newSelection = getSharedPreferences(TAG, MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("list_selection", 0);
    if (newSelection != selectedItemPosition) {
        selectedItemPosition = newSelection;
        listView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listView.setSelection(selectedItemPosition);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I assume that it would works well when using an `ArrayAdapter`, but when using a `CursorAdapter`. The setSelection method will be called when `cursorAdapter.getCount() == 0`, which makes the `setSelection` not working.

So my question is how to make this `setSelection` working with `CursorAdapter`?

Comment: Try stopping this check:  if (newSelection != selectedItemPosition)

Answer (score 0):

I should move the code inside onResume to `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>.onLoadedFinished`, which makes the `cursorAdapter.getCount()` equals to real count.